# Tkinter button distance from window edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is there a way using Tkinter to have buttons so that they are always placed a certain number of pixels from the edge of the window, even when the window is resized? I've tried using anchors but that didn't seem to move the placement in the window that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can anchor buttons or any other widget to the sides of a window by starting with a *Frame*, and configuring its rows and columns to have a weight of *1* in order for it to fill the parent window.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
frame.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
```

Then, for each button you want to use *sticky* to anchor it to the respective side, and use *padx* or *pady* to add some padding (in pixels) between the button and the window.

```
top_padding = 5
top = ttk.Button(frame, text="Top")
top.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N, pady=(top_padding, 0))

left_padding = 5
left = ttk.Button(frame, text="Left")
left.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=(left_padding, 0))

right_padding = 5
right = ttk.Button(frame, text="Right")
right.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.E, padx=(0, right_padding))

bottom_padding = 5
bottom = ttk.Button(frame, text="Bottom")
bottom.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.S, pady=(0, bottom_padding))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I shall have to try this tomorrow morning, but it looks like it will solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the `padx` function?
it works like this:

```
button=Button(place,text="something something", padx=10)
```

it provides with extra horizontal padding between widgets, aditionally, you could use [frames](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)  with padx and an anchor so the text is fixated to a position